# MySQL 5.7 (5.7.38): install audit plugin

Tags: mysql, audit

To get a audit trail of users/hosts they're connecting to a MySQL server, I would like to install an audit plugin. I read a lot about the MariaDB server_audit
plugin. However, when I try to install this plugin MySQL crashes when a new connection is made; it looks like this is a known problem. When I try to install
a very new version, the installation fails: ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/libaudit_plugin.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/libaudit_plugin.so:
undefined symbol: _ZN11Query_cache21send_result_to_clientEP3THDPcj)

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with MySQL 5.7.38. Which plugin version (and where to find) can I use? Or is there a better sollution, for example another plugin
that does the same? The only thing I need is a log with timestamps and the host/user they're connecting.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the MariaDB audit log? I use that (although not with 5.7.38 yet) but the file is called `server_audit.so`.  I thought that `libaudit_plugin.so` was the McAffee Audit plugin?

Comment: Yes. wrong copy-paste; I tried the Mcafee plugin as well.